# Vertices that create a convex quadrilateral

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

In how many ways can we choose 4 vertices of a convex n-gon that create a convex quadrilateral (All the inside angles are less than 180) with at least 2 sides of the quadrilateral being sides of the n-gon? 
(Consider $n >4$)

Comment: There are $\dbinom{n}{2}$ ways in which we can choose the two sides  of the $n$-gon that are sides of the quadrilateral.

But we are counting the ones that have three sides of the $n$-gons as sides of the quadrilateral. There are $n$ of this, and we are overcounting them $\dbinom{3}{2} = 3$ times. 

Therefore, the answer is $\dbinom{n}{2} - 2n$.
I just want to check if my answer is right.

Comment: @Epic Alomost, but not quite. If you choose $AB$ and $BC$ out of $ABC\ldots Z$, say. there are several more solutions than just $ABCD$ and $ABCZ$ (which are also counted under $(AB,CD)$ and $(ZA, BC)$. There are also $ABCE, ABCF,\ldots , ABCY$.

Comment: Oooops! I forgot about the arrangements with two consecutive sides. Let me work on my proof.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the convexity requirement of the quadrilateral can be
ignored because any quadrilateral using $4$ of the vertices of a
convex $n$-gon is necessarily convex.

For the trivial case of $n=4$, the answer is obviously $1$. We
assume now that $n \geq 5$.

There are $n$ quadrilaterals with $3$ consecutive sides from the
$n$-gon because you can position these $3$ sides in any of $n$
places and there is then only $1$ choice for the $4^{th}$ side.

There are $n\left(n-5\right)$ quadrilaterals with exactly $2$
consecutive sides from the $n$-gon. This is because there are $n$
places to position the consecutive sides, and for each of these,
$n-5$ choices for the $4^{th}$ vertex.

There are $\dfrac{n\left(n-5\right)}{2}$ quadrilaterals with two
non-consecutive sides from the $n$-gon. This is because there a $n$
ways to choose the first side, then $n-5$ ways to choose the second
side (there must be a gap of $2$ sides between the two sides we
choose otherwise we get $3$ consecutive sides). Also, the order of
first and second sides doesn't matter so we divide our count by $2$.

Summing these counts, we get the answer:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Total} &=& n + n\left(n-5\right) +
\dfrac{n\left(n-5\right)}{2} \\
&=& n + \dfrac{3n\left(n-5\right)}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Can I count with stars and bars method?

Comment: @minthao_2011 I suspect not but you could try it and check your answers for small values of $n$.